# Expose local server on https://192.168.1.4:443 to internet

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, webserver, expose

I have local server running on port 443 under https protocol and I need it to be reachable not only from local network, but from whole internet. 
It's connected using TOTOLINK N300RT router. I tried to do port forwarding, but it didn't help. I found my external ip on https://www.myip.com/ and use it in url, but it still refuses to connect.
Any advice on how can I configure my router to allow requests?
Tried ngrok, and it just hangs infinitely when I enter any http command..

Comment: If configured correctly, port forwarding should work. See this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KqHRND-8d-I

Comment: Yes, I understand that router configuration is a key to solve the problem, but, unfortunately, I don't know how to configure it correctly. I did see this video before, but it didn't give me understanding on what is going on there. Additionally, description specified that video applies to  A2004NS , A5004NS , A1004NS , A6004NS models, but not to mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to assign the internal IP 192.168.1.4 and port 443 to correspond with your external IP W.X.Y.Z. and any port you choose for that purpose.

After you did that, test if the port is actually open with [this tool](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/).

Note that in order for everything to work, your server must actually run on 443. If no service is alive there to listen to that port, your forwarding will have no effect. Also, make sure that 443 is not blocked by your local server firewall.

Comment: Thank you for this information, it is actually helpful. One thing I can't figure out is: how to open the port? I'm using the tool that you've mentioned, but all ports seem to be closed..

Comment: If you use something like 192.168.1.4:443 forwarded to 1.2.3.4:8433 then your local server firewall must allow 443 incoming and the router must allow 8433 incoming. If this is correctly done you should have a successful test of open port if you test 8433 with an external open-port tester.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm not entirely sure what exactly I did right, but I allowed these ports in server firewall, created port forwarding in router for these ports, rebooted everything, added a little bit of suffering and it suddenly works :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to publish your server on another external port? you can publish an internal port like 443 on different external port for example 4433. and remember some times in some service providers or some countries including my country (Iran) default encrypted ports are filtered. or even encrypted services on all ports are filtered by some kind of deep protocol inspection.

edit: and one more thing, some time 443 on routers is in used by the router it self for management.

Comment: default gateway of your server must be the ip of your router

Comment: Yes, I used 8433 at first, but it didn't matter. Now seems like all my local ports are closed to internet, although I even created firewall rules to allow them